# Azure Devops Board aligment in text on description column

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When migrating the text(Description) to azure board its not proper way aligned, is there any way to resolve this issue. thanks

Attached screen shot for the reference

(i am ok with query or coding formatting) also

thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGcn8.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common question when copying and pasting the formatted text across products/platforms.

Current we have no good method to avoid/resolve the issue.

Most of the times, you need to manually adjust the format to be the right one.